# Group By in Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have two models

```
class ShareType(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=False)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=56, null=False, blank=False)

class ShareAllocation(models.Model):
    session_key = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
    share_type = models.ForeignKey(ShareType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    share_holder = models.ForeignKey(ShareHolder, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    number_of_shares = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    amount_paid = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    amount_unpaid = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    is_beneficial_owner = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False)
```

i am using this query, which is obviously incorrect.

```
share_structure = ShareType.objects.annotate(Sum('shareallocation__number_of_shares')).\
                filter(shareallocation__session_key=self.storage.request.session.session_key)
```

sample data for shareallocation table

```
12,5,2,1,false,9,9,098fiy6m9f0tkkmnk8jr715pyjlzcai6
13,10,2,1,false,10,12,098fiy6m9f0tkkmnk8jr715pyjlzcai6
14,15,2,1,false,12,12,098fiy6m9f0tkkmnk8jr715pyjlzcai6
```

sample data for share type table

```
9,ORD,(ORD) Ordinary 
10,A,(A) A 
11,B,(B) B 
12,MAN,(MAN) Management 
13,LG,(LG) Life Governors 
14,EMP,(EMP) Employees 
15,FOU,(FOU) Founders 
16,PRF,(PRF) Preference 
17,CUMP,(CUMP) Cumulative Preference 
18,NCP,(NCP) Non Cumulative Preference 
19,REDP,(REDP) Redeemable Preference 
20,NRP,(NRP) Non Redeemable Preference 
21,NCRP,(NCRP) Non Cum. Redeemable Preference 
22,PARP,(PARP) Participative Preference 
23,RED,(RED) Redeemable 
24,INI,(INI) Initial 
25,SPE,(SPE) Special
```

required output:

- Code
- Number Of Shares(total)
- Amount Paid(total)
- Amount Unpaid(total)

Comment: Please share sample data, desired output and your current output.

Comment: added in data and output in orignal post

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way can be to put a function inside your ShareType Model for number of shares, amount paid, and amount unpaid

```
from django.db.models import Sum

class ShareType(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=False)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=56, null=False, blank=False)

    def number_of_shares(self):
        return ShareAllocation.objects.filter(share_type = self).count()
    
    def amount_paid(self):
        return ShareAllocation.objects.filter(share_type = self).aggregate(Sum('amount_paid'))

    def amount_unpaid(self):
        return ShareAllocation.objects.filter(share_type = self).aggregate(Sum('amount_unpaid')) 

class ShareAllocation(models.Model):
    session_key = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
    share_type = models.ForeignKey(ShareType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    share_holder = models.ForeignKey(ShareHolder, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    number_of_shares = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    amount_paid = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    amount_unpaid = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    is_beneficial_owner = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False)
```

then you can read those values as if they were fields

Comment: i tried something as well, not really getting there,                                           
`share_structure = ShareAllocation.objects.\
                values('share_type__code','number_of_shares').\
                filter(session_key=self.storage.request.session.session_key).\
                annotate(Count('share_type__code')).\
                annotate(Sum('number_of_shares'))`

Comment: try this share_structure = ShareAllocation.objects.filter(session_key=self.storage.request.session.session_key).annotate(number_shares=Count('sharetype')).annotate(amount_paid=Sum('sharetype__amount_paid'))

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what is called change! i have a feeling there is going to be alot of it that i am going to see...that aside

here is the solution

```
    share_structure = ShareAllocation.objects.values('share_type__code','share_type__type').\
        annotate(share_count=Sum('share_type')). \
        annotate(number_of_shares=Sum('number_of_shares')).\
        annotate(amount_paid=Sum('amount_paid')).\
        annotate(amount_unpaid=Sum('amount_unpaid'))
```

the challenge was in understanding or lack of understanding that all of my column names will come from values field.

The major learning from this exercise shows that column for referenced table will go in values as tablename__filedname
and summed columns will come from the annotate function